# How to acces stl() output values in R

Tags: r

I know this is a simple question for skilled user of R, but I don't know how to access the stl output. I googled it for a while but i didn't found any tutorial. This is what i mean, I have this little sequence of command

```
   dd<-read.table('data.dat')
   ddts<-ts(dd,start=1,freq=300)
   stldd<-stl(ddts,s.window='periodic')
```

know i want to perform a fit on the trend part of stldd, but I don't know how to access it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `str` to view the structure of an object. `stl` objects are quite complicated, but you can extract the trend using:

```
stldd$time.series[,"trend"]
```